# jekyll plugin not working, can't find plugin

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

I'm new to ruby ,when i want to use github build a blog,and i added a plugin
`slashdotdash/jekyll-lunr-js-search` for full text search, I put `jekyll-lunr-js-search.rb` 
under `./_plugins`,then I added `gems:[jekyll-lunr-js-search]` to my `_config.yml`, after this I can't build site, got this error:

```
ray@ubuntu:/var/www/ss$ jekyll build -t
Configuration file: /var/www/ss/_config.yml

/home/ray/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:
in require': cannot load such file -- jekyll-lunr-js-search.rb (LoadError) from    /home/ray/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require'
from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/jekyll-1.3.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:81:in block in setup'
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed..I should not add this `gems:[jekyll-lunr-js-search]` to`_config.yml`...